# How to permanently add macros to Excel as part of the program?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have a macro where I'm not sure when I will need to use it.

I need them built into Excel to be able use them at every start of the program – like you would install some add-on (e.g. Kutools).

How can I do it?

Comment: What you're looking for is [the personal macro workbook](http://superuser.com/questions/388806/how-do-i-use-excel-2010-personal-macro-workbook)

Answer (score 3):

In excel 2010, the personal macro workbook is located at `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.xlsb`. The best way to [create](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-HA102174076.aspx) this is to record a macro into your personal macro workbook. You do this by:

1. Enabling the developer tab by going to `File - Options - Customize Ribbon` and checking `developer` on the right side of the screen 
   [image]
2. Go to the developer tab and click on `record macro` 
   [image]
3. `Store Macro In` your `Personal Macro Workbook` 
   [image]
4. `Stop Recording` macro 
   [image]
5. When you close out of excel or the workbook, it will prompt you **Do you want to save the changes you made to PERSONAL.xlsb** select `save`
   [image]

   You will now have a personal macro workbook that is visible anytime you open excel. If you have macros stored in other workbooks you can transfer them to the personal macro workbook by moving the modules within `Visual Basic` in excel. Additionally, if you have a workbook with a lot of macros, you can navigate to the file location and rename that workbook to PERSONAL and save it as .xlsb

Comment: It is not working to me. I have that macro in my Personal macros file. But when I pick it, click: run. It doesnt work. It must be an issue during recording it. There must be some some order how to record it. Probably I did it in wrong way in detail while recording.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a method to use and distribute your VBA solutions (e.g. allow other users to access UDF's you've created and used in your workbooks), you can easily create an Excel Add-in.  Generally, you'll:

1. Create a new, blank workbook and create your VBA solution.
2. Save your new workbook as a .XLAM (Excel add-in).
3. Use Excel to add your
   add-in; then distribute or make available as necessary.

See [Microsoft's detailed directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx) here.

Comment: I have tried it also. Can't make it work. Also have some problems with kind of permission in excel. It is saying me to run as 'unhidden'. I don't know where to enable it.