# MS Access Personal Macro Workbook

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vba, macros, microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2013

In MS Excel I have a personal macro workbook that is with me no matter what excel file I open. Is there a similar solution available for MS Access?

The reason I am working on this is that i want to make an Autofit Columns macro that will go through all available tables and autofit each column, and I want it to be readily available no matter what db I'm in. If anyone has suggestions that will help with that or a quick keyboard shortcut that would work just as well?

Comment: No. Your best bet would be to keep your code snippets in a text file so that you could bring them in when you need them.

Comment: So, no personal WB for Access? Drat.

Comment: Well, none up to access 2010. Maybe in 2013, or maybe you could cobble one together by placing it in the similar location (for access) as it is in excel - [see here](http://superuser.com/questions/388806/how-do-i-use-excel-2010-personal-macro-workbook). I'm not well versed with anything office 2013 or windows 8. My thoughts, however, are that because access is database-driven, there's no *workbook* for it to remember to open. Maybe it's called something else.