# How can I create an Excel Menubar Button to run a Macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, plugins

**Background:** I created a macro for a friend that will create a pivot table from a large worksheet of data. The data will always have the same number of columns with the same column headers; the number of rows is dynamic.

**Question:** Assuming my macro is written correctly, is there a way for me to add this macro as a button in Excel so that whenever my friend opens up a spreadsheet in Excel, she can just click the button to run the macro? I guess it would have to be installed as a plugin/add-in of sorts so that it still shows if she closes Excel and reopens it?

Comment: You can add it to a control button no problem. Or you could put it in her [Personal Macro Workbook](http://superuser.com/questions/388806/how-do-i-use-excel-2010-personal-macro-workbook) so she could run it on any sheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your macro to the Ribbon as follows:

1. Right-click the Ribbon and select "Customize the Ribbon".
2. In the `Choose commands from:` field on the top-left of the dialog, select "Macros". Click your macro.
3. In the `Customize the Ribbon:` field on the top-right, ensure "Main Tabs" is selected.
4. Expand the desired tab.
5. If you already have a custom group, select it. Otherwise, click the `New Group` button (or press `Alt-N`) and name it something. I usually use "Other".
6. Click the `Add` button in the center of the screen (or press `Alt-A`). Your macro appears in the custom group.

   - You can change the name and symbol using the `Rename` button (or pressing `Alt-M`).
7. Click the `OK` button. Your macro now appears as specified.

Comment: You're welcome. =) Glad I can be of service.