# Excel 2007 Automatic workbook calculation keeps going to manual

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

The excel 2007 that I have somehow not updating the formula cells, I go to Excel Option > Formulas > Workbook Calculation and the options keeps going to manual for some reason. I uninstalled Office completely and re-install and the problem still exists. Any help is really appreciated.

Update 25/4/2015: I tried the method mentioned in this [forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/206965-manual-calculation-startup.html), I'm testing it now. Anyone can confirm this method ?

Comment: Yes, whatever your template is can affect this. Also any macros in that workbook or your [personal macro workbook](http://superuser.com/questions/388806/how-do-i-use-excel-2010-personal-macro-workbook).

Comment: I'm sure there is no macros. About the template do you mean that whenever there is an .xlt file Excel will read it and its settings ?

Comment: Yes, using a template will have excel use those settings.