# How do I use Excel 2011 Personal Macro Workbook?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2011

I realized I [asked about excel 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/388806/how-do-i-use-excel-2010-personal-macro-workbook), but that only covers Windows OS. How can I use the Personal Macro Workbook in Excel 2011 on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first Microsoft [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288117) that shows up for the Personal Macro Workbook in OSX ***erroneously*** lists the location of the workbook as:

```
Hard disk drive:Applications:Microsoft Office version:Office:Startup:Excel:Personal Macro Workbook
```

In OSX Yosemite (10.10), the location of the Personal Macro Workbook is different. Starting at *`/home/`* or *`/Users/$username`*:

```
`~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Excel/Personal Macro Workbook.xlsb`
```

The easiest way to create this is to record a *dummy* macro. In excel, you first need to ensure the *Developer* tab is enabled by going to *Excel → Preferences → Sharing and Privacy → Ribbon → Customize* and in the *Show or Hide Tabs* area, make sure the *Developer* checkbox is checked:

[image]

Once this is enabled, you'll see the *Developer Tab* on the ribbon:

[image]

Now, hit the record button and choose to store the macro in Personal Macro Workbook:

[image]

[image]

Once you click OK, click the record button again to stop recording:

[image]

Now, you'll see the Personal Macro Workbook Module in the Visual Basic Editor's Project Pane:

[image]

To save, exit excel and choose to save changes:

[image]

Now, you'll have the Personal Macro Workbook available to you anytime you use excel. You can create and save frequently used macros so they are easily available, or you could even rename a workbook you already have that has a bunch of macros and replace the one you just created.

Comment: I am on macOS high sierra, apparently that file doesn't exist

Comment: Which version of Excel? 2016 removed most support for VBA on OSX I believe

Comment: Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 15.41

Comment: Nope https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/9098431-bring-back-a-fully-functional-vbe-visual-basic-ed